# PHP example from tutorial won't run all the way through

Tags: php, debugging

I've placed an `echo` before and after it stops running. The file `file1.txt` is written, but then the final `echo` confirmation is not returned.

```
<?php
$fh = fopen("file1.txt", 'w') or die("Failed to create file");
$text = <<<_END
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3

_END;
fwrite($fh, $text) or die("Could not write to file");

echo "This shows up in my browser";
$fclose($fh);
echo "This doesn't";
?>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your script has error

Replace

```
 $fclose($fh);
```

With

```
 fclose($fh);
```

To see all the error add this to the top of your page

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors','On');
```

Since you are learning if you want to play around with variable functions this would work

```
$fclose = "fclose";
$fclose ($fh);
```

Finally a simpler version of your code for learning purpose using `file_put_contents` http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php

```
$text = <<<_END
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
_END;
file_put_contents ("file1.txt", $text );
echo "This shows up in my browser";
```

Answer (score 2):

`$fclose($fh);` should be `fclose($fh);`. This is a function, not variable.